# MySQL user seems to be losing permissions

Tags: mysql

We have noticed that our mysql user seems to be losing permissions.

When the server was setup we created the db with

`CREATE USER user;`

Then

`CREATE DATABASE DB;`

and then

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB.* TO 'user'@'localhost';`

The server runs mysql and various parts of wordpress have stopped working recently.

The fix was to do

`GRANT DELETE, SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';`

and then this was repeated for SELECT, INSERT etc

so taking effect globally.  This is not something that we did when the server was setup and it's been working fine without it - nothing has changed in the server.

What could have caused this?

Comment: What do you see when you do `SHOW GRANTS FOR user@localhost`?

Comment: ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'```

```GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost'```

I've never had to set global permissions before

Comment: Do you have any other databases that wordpress needs to use? The first only gives the user access to one database, the second gives them access to all.

Comment: One DB, one user, it seems like GRANT ALL, isnt granting all - if it is, then they're not sticking for some reason

Comment: Maybe WordPress uses internal databases like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Is it possible to get the actual error that occurs?